# How to Get the height of String text in each row of tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

Data is coming from api and i want to increase the cell height according to the height of text coming from api.
I want to show more text in my label, but it cuts of because of small cell.

[image]

I did `UItableViewAutomationDimenension`, but it didn't exactly work for me.

Please tell me if anyone knows.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: All you have to do is pin the top and bottom of the label to the contentView (assuming label will always be bigger than image) of the cell using autolayout. Then set the numberOfLines to 0. Autolayout and automatic dimension will take care of the rest.

Comment: Yeah i  have also given the top and bottom of label to the view and assign label to 0 for multiple lines and its works good, but the issue is that , when the label is increase, the cell cuts off the label, bcoz its height is 100.0

Comment: You don’t need to set cell height because automatic dimension will tale care of height.

Comment: Yeah , but it doesn't work actually like this, its work when i'm using textLabel, but when use custom label, it doesn't

Comment: @ZainShahzad you don't have to set height, you can do it with UItableViewAutomationDimenension , just try this sample project i have created for chat screen: https://github.com/iamshezad/SHChatScreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func heightForText(string: String, width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let attrString = NSAttributedString(
        string: string,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])
    let size = attrString.boundingRect(
    with: CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), 
    options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
    return size.height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some work on this, I found the solution.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if msg1[indexPath.row].messageType == "image"{
            return 185.0
        }
        else{
            let attrString = NSAttributedString(
                string: msg1[indexPath.row].message!,
                attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)])
            let size = attrString.boundingRect(
                with: CGSize(width: 200, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

            return size.height + 35
        }
```

So it gives a result output like this:

[image]

Anyway Thanks to all for your Answers...!!!

Comment: Hey, your solution works but why did you add 35 with the heigh while returning??

Comment: @AsifSyeed it's just to give some padding space. Not compulsory...